# How to apply a function to dataframes within a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

For this data:

```
list_data1 <- data.frame(date=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), X0=c(3, 9, 5, 1, -2, 8),
                         X1=c(3, 9, 5, 1, -2, 8), mod=c("mod", "mod", "mod"))
list_data2 <- data.frame(date=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), X0=c(3, 9, 5, 1, -2, 8),
                         X1=c(3, 9, 5, 1, -2, 8), mod=c("mod", "mod", "mod"))
merged.list <- list(list_data1, list_data2)
```

I need to replace values X0 and X1  by   `X0 - mean(X0[1:3])` and `X1 - mean(X1[1:3])`.

I have other columns X2,X3 etc.  so I want to apply the functions on all columns except mod and date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rapply` on numeric columns.

```
FUN <- function(x) x - mean(x[1:3])
r <- rapply(merged.list, f=FUN, classes="numeric", how="replace")
r
# [[1]]
#   date         X0         X1 mod
# 1  Jan -2.6666667 -2.6666667 mod
# 2  Feb  3.3333333  3.3333333 mod
# 3  Mar -0.6666667 -0.6666667 mod
# 4  Jan -4.6666667 -4.6666667 mod
# 5  Feb -7.6666667 -7.6666667 mod
# 6  Mar  2.3333333  2.3333333 mod
# 
# [[2]]
#   date         X0         X1 mod
# 1  Jan -2.6666667 -2.6666667 mod
# 2  Feb  3.3333333  3.3333333 mod
# 3  Mar -0.6666667 -0.6666667 mod
# 4  Jan -4.6666667 -4.6666667 mod
# 5  Feb -7.6666667 -7.6666667 mod
# 6  Mar  2.3333333  2.3333333 mod
```

Comment: Did not think of `rapply()`, nice one!

Comment: Both answers work great. which one shall I accept?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply()`

**Code**

```
lapply(merged.list, function(z){
  # X0 - mean(X0[1:3])
  z[, "X0"] <- z[, "X0"] - mean(z[, "X0"][1:3])

  # X1 - mean(X1[1:3])
  z[, "X1"] <- z[, "X1"] - mean(z[, "X1"][1:3])

  # return df
  z
})

# [[1]]
#   date         X0         X1 mod
# 1  Jan -2.6666667 -2.6666667 mod
# 2  Feb  3.3333333  3.3333333 mod
# 3  Mar -0.6666667 -0.6666667 mod
# 4  Jan -4.6666667 -4.6666667 mod
# 5  Feb -7.6666667 -7.6666667 mod
# 6  Mar  2.3333333  2.3333333 mod

# [[2]]
#   date         X0         X1 mod
# 1  Jan -2.6666667 -2.6666667 mod
# 2  Feb  3.3333333  3.3333333 mod
# 3  Mar -0.6666667 -0.6666667 mod
# 4  Jan -4.6666667 -4.6666667 mod
# 5  Feb -7.6666667 -7.6666667 mod
# 6  Mar  2.3333333  2.3333333 mod
```

**Update**

If you want to apply the calculations to all numeric columns in your `data.frame()`

```
lapply(merged.list, function(z){
  # select all numeric columns
  tmp1 <- z[, sapply(z, is.numeric)]
  
  # do calcs
  tmp2 <- sapply(tmp1, function(x){
    x - mean(x[1:3])
  })
  
  # reassign to original data.frames
  z[, sapply(z, is.numeric)] <- tmp2
  
  # return
  z
})
```

Comment: Both answers work great. which one shall I accept?

Comment: @Tpellirn accept whichever answer you like best, it is completely up to you. However, If I was you I would probably accept Jay's answer since it is more straightforward to read.